# LLVM C++ : compiler fail to identify primitive type of class member as const

Tags: c++, macos

Consider the following class in which I define 2 static variables with constant value and initialisation upon declaration.

Both variable are primitive, but for the string initialisation I get the following error when compiling with LLVM (clang) `Non-const static data member must be initialized out of line` even though its type is preceded by `const`. In visual studio, the same code passed compilation.

perhaps anybody can explain this discrepancy ?

```
class my class 
{
public:
    // the variable in this line is recognised as non-const. 
    // Therefore, it doesn't allow initialisation.
    static const wchar_t* bla = L"000111"; 
    
    // this line compiles perfectly well. 
    static const int bla2 = 128; 
}
```

Comment: Just because something "is preceded by `const`" doesn't make it `const`. C++ is not that simple. `const wchar_t *` is a pointer to constant `wchar_t`s. It is not, itself, a `const`. There is a big difference between a pointer to something that's `const`, and a `const` pointer to something. Two completely different things.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, thanks for you comment. is there any way to make this pointer `const` rather than pointing to `const wchar_t*` ?

Comment: Of course there is. This should be explained in a chapter in every C++ textbook that explains how types are declared in C++. Unfortunately, Stackoverflow is not a replacement for a C++ textbook, and it wouldn't make any sense to copy/paste entire chapters from textbooks, here. I expect that every textbook will discuss the three different ways to use the `const` keyword: a constant object or a pointer, a pointer to a constant object, and a constant class method. You could also try searching Stackoverflow, you might also find previous questions regarding this topic.